# How long is Miso Paste good for in the fridge after opening?

Tags: spoilage

I'm not sure how to judge the fridge life of this stuff, does this salty stuff last awhile?

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this because Miso paste is different from other foods covered in the listed duplicate. It therefore warrants a separate answer.

Comment: @GdD - The website [StillTasty](http://stilltasty.com/) is the first link in the linked duplicate that is recommended to check for specific foods, and it has an entry for miso.  Your comment does bring up a larger question about that duplicate answer's formatting though -- perhaps the link to that database should be placed near the beginning of the question, so people who are re-routed there can immediately search for their food.

Answer (score 4):

Miso paste lasts literal years in the refrigerator, although past a year it starts to lose flavor. It can also dry out if it isn't sealed well, which isn't a problem as you rehydrate it before drinking anyway - it just takes a bit longer to dissolve.

Comment: Drinking Miso Paste?  Whatever floats your boat I suppose.

Comment: Miso soup is diluted miso paste. Very tasty @SomethingSomething.